# Does the housing act 1988 have any associated explanatory notes?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research, legislation

I can’t find them where they would seemingly normally be at https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/notes. Does this mean that they don’t exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Not all Acts have explanatory notes.

Specifically (as the [legislation website](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/help) explains):

> Explanatory Notes were introduced in 1999 and accompany all Public Acts except Appropriation, Consolidated Fund, Finance and Consolidation Acts.

Looking around the site, it looks more like *most*, rather than *all*, such Acts since then have explanatory notes. But in any case, the Housing Act 1988 predates their introduction, so no notes exist.